# running vertx behind a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, vert.x

Has anybody had a luck trying to use vertx bihind a corporate proxy? I have tried whatever possible ways that comes to my head to provide the proxy information to vertx. Nothing works so far.

set environment variable http_proxy=http://mycorporate.proxy.com:8080 - no luck

set environment variable VERTX_OPTS='-Dhttp.proxyHost=mycorporate.proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080' - no luck

set environment variables 
http.proxyHost=mycorporate.proxy.com
http.proxyPort=8080 
no luck

Injecting extra echo into vertx command I can see that proxy related parameters are being passed to JVM correctly but required module still can't be downloaded ("vertx run hello.js" just stuck obviously trying to download io.vertx~lang-rhino~2.0.0-final)

Proxy itself is ok - I'm using it with no problem for maven, sbt and other different stuff requiring proxy
Same laptop being used from home can successfully run "vertx run hello.js" with downloading io.vertx~lang-rhino~2.0.0-final (for the first run)

I have just started evaluating vertx for our company needs and this is my very first choking point hindering my further attempts to make a decision. So far I have to follow next steps as workaround: 1 Run from home and get whatever required modules in sys-mods. 2 Manually upload the module(s) to sys-mods on the test server when back to the office.
Obviously this is not a normal way to run anything.

Comment: When I solved this, I specified the manual proxy server -- not the automatic one. Once connected, it was then necessary to invoke vert.x once for every component to download before it would successfully deploy the verticle.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. I figure out that HttpClient form  does not read settings from JVM_OPTS.
So solution was following:

Edit your vertx.bat(sh)

```
set JVM_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxxx -Dhttp.proxyPort=xxxx
```

and then in code related to httpClient try sth like this

```
   HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
    String proxyHost = System.getProperty("http.proxyHost", "none");
    Integer proxyPort = Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort", "80"));

    if(!"none".equalsIgnoreCase(proxyHost)){

        client.setHost(proxyHost);
        client.setPort(proxyPort);
    }
```

and later in code releted to HTTP request

```
   MultiMap map = new CaseInsensitiveMultiMap();
   map.add("Host", domainName); //get domain of REQUESTED_URL                 
   client.getNow(REQUESTED_URL, map, new new Handler<HttpClientResponse>(){...});
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the vertx3 http client doesn't have the mentioned methods (setHost() and setPort()).

Answer (score 1):

Building on @kamyk-pl answer. If you are using latest version of Vertx this is what you can do :

```
    WebClientOptions webClientOptions = new WebClientOptions();
    String proxyHost = System.getProperty("http.proxyHost", "none");
    Integer proxyPort = Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort", "80"));

    if(!"none".equalsIgnoreCase(proxyHost)){
        ProxyOptions proxyOptions = new ProxyOptions();
        proxyOptions.setHost(proxyHost);
        proxyOptions.setPort(proxyPort);
        webClientOptions.setProxyOptions(proxyOptions);
    }

     WebClient.create(vertx, webClientOptions)
```

Optionally you also want to add this if you are testing SSL connections

```
        webClientOptions.setVerifyHost(false);
        webClientOptions.setTrustAll(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use vertx 3.8.0

```java
                HttpClient c = vertx.createHttpClient();
                        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                        requestOptions.setHost(ip).setPort(port).setURI("http://httpbin.org/ip");
                        c.request(HttpMethod.GET, requestOptions).handler(new Handler<HttpClientResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(HttpClientResponse event) {
                                event.handler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void handle(Buffer event) {
                                        System.out.println(event);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).end();
```

Answer (score -3):

To set the proxy, edit vertx.bat (if you are on Windows) and add

```
set JVM_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxxx -Dhttp.proxyPort=xxxx
```